# Building a Gantt-Chart in iPad UIView

Tags: ios, gantt-chart

I need to draw a Gantt-Chart within my iPad App. Are there any frameworks out there or examples to do this? I've searched the web and found nothing helpful till now. If I find something I will post it here later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing "ready-to-use". The solution is using quartz 2d classes to draw the gantt yourself

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself, but the [iqwidgets](https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets) library includes a Gantt view.