# What are the best ways to plot Gantt charts in ipad sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I have to draw Gantt charts in ipad, could you suggest how to draw such charts?
What are the API's available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Gantt-Chart in iPad UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260622/building-a-gantt-chart-in-ipad-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't Api which draws Gantt Chart. You should draw it using [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html).